# Help with type of layout

Tags: java, android, layout

what type of layout should i be used for a layout like this?
[image]

Should i be used linear layout or relative? Could you explain why you chose the layout you did. A sample would be helpful as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#ff00" android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_height="100dp" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"></RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#f0f0" android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"></RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your layout is as simple as the above shown, I would use LinearLayout - mostly because I find working with relative layouts a bit annoying and harder to find bugs in.

A sample would be:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">
         <!-- Put widgets here -->
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:background="@android:color/background_light">
         <!-- Put widgets here -->
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Couple of notes, the first Linear says that the height is wrap_content, doesn't that mean it'll expand as content gets added? Is the second linear positioned at the bottom of the screen? It looks like it just sits below the top one.

Comment: The trick here is the layout_weight="1" for the first LinearLayout. This serves the purpose of telling the layout to take up all availible space left - not matter its content or own layout_height value. This also positions the second layout at the bottom of the screen because it will only take up 100dp of the height, leaving the rest for the first layout.